Can i use subxt to to get unapplied slashes or even slashes that have occured in a live chain?
I need to get the validators and their nominators who were slashed in a particular era on a live chain. I tried to get the unapplied slashes using the snippet below. But when doing so I get the following error.

Error: Rpc(ClientError(Transport(Invalid URL: No port number in URL (default port is not supported))))

Code snippet using subxt v0.25.0

use subxt::{OnlineClient, PolkadotConfig};

#[subxt::subxt(runtime_metadata_path="./metadata.scale")]
pub mod polkadot{}
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>>{
   let api:OnlineClient<PolkadotConfig> = OnlineClient::from_url("wss://my_websocket_endpoint.net").await?;

    let uaps=polkadot::storage().staking().unapplied_slashes(5);
    let era=api.storage().fetch(&uaps, None).await?.unwrap();
    for i in era{
      println!("AccountId of validator: {}", i.validator);
      println!("Validator_slash: {}", i.own);
      println!("{:?}",i.others);
    }
    Ok(())
}


The error is pretty clear.
Error: Rpc(ClientError(Transport(Invalid URL: No port number in URL (default port is not supported))))

The URL format is incorrect. Use wss://my_websocket_endpoint.net:$PORT.
For example ws://localhost:9944.

I am pretty sure I am trying to connect to a mainnet. This is not a devnet. This takes me back to my question. Is it even possible to connect to a mainnet?

I mean you can not ignore the port part in the url, even it's wss. For polkadot, it should be wss://rpc.polkadot.io:443 instead of wss://rpc.polkadot.io.

More example, https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/06a1c3f74174f0674ebabe1bbd35872240c14edf/examples/parachain-example/README.md?plain=1#L72.
Use wss://polkadot-asset-hub-rpc.polkadot.io:443 instead of wss://polkadot-asset-hub-rpc.polkadot.io.
Does this clear now?

Just to add: If you update to a newer version of Subxt (0.25 is almost 2yrs old, 0.37 is current ATM), I don't think you need to provide an explicit port number any more and it'll be inferred from the protocol

Ok. I understand what you are trying to say.
